# AS2 vs AS3 communication protocol difference. Server requirement

Tags: protocol

I'm researching what's needed for EDI as far as protocols and server/application setup.
This is transportation industry and I'm interested in X12 format for transactions like 204, 210, 214.

Specific question is:
Do BOTH trading partners have to run servers? With AS3 it seems like SFTP server and it seems like one partner can run it and another partner can push/pull.

What about AS2? Can it have server only on one side? Or both partners should be able to push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, for AS2 both sides run HTTP server. Here is good explanation on how this works:

http://as2integration.org/display/AS2/AS2+Protocol+Operation

I also was able to develop our own AS2 server and sender based on IIS WCF stack + EldoS EDIBlackBox